# SSED Remove Multiline XML Code

Tags: xml, scripting, batch-file, batch-processing, multiline

I'm trying to use SSED to delete multilines from a XML File. I am able to delete certain single lines within the XML file, but I need to be able to remove multilines.

For example:

```
<tagnumberone>
   <tagInside>This must not be deleted</tagInside>
</tagnumberone>
<tagnumberone>
   <tagInside>This must be deleted</tagInside>
</tagnumberone>
<tagnumberone>
   <tagInside>This must not be deleted</tagInside>
</tagnumberone>
```

So what it means that I need to be able to delete the line of code This must be deleted> and then it's outertags as well so that I get following result:

```
<tagnumberone>
   <tagInside>This must not be deleted</tagInside>
</tagnumberone>
<tagnumberone>
   <tagInside>This must not be deleted</tagInside>
</tagnumberone>
```

I am trying to use following Super Sed commando: 
`ssed s:\<tagnumberone\>\<tagInside\>This must be deleted\<\/tagInside\>\<\/tagnumberone\>:: <file.xml >out.xmle`

This gives me the following error: unterminated 's' command.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already try to simplify the command by removing parts of it until you don't get the error message anymore? This might help you finding out what is causing the error.

Comment: Yes I did. If I just take one line, for instance (<tagInside>blbalbalba) then it get's removed. So trying to delete multilines gives an error. 
I think the line breaks are giving a problem. But if I add \n as a line break, the error says: The system cannot specify the file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Actually, I don't know why it's working but nevertheless, it works. If someone now can explain to me the following code, that would be awesome:

```
ssed /<tagnumberone>/!b;N;N;/<tagnumberone>\s*\n\s*<tagInside>This must be deleted<\/tagInside>\s*\n\s*<\/tagnumberone>/d <oldFile >newFile
```

Thanks!

Comment: You will find the answer [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) Look for `N` & 'd' commands & regex section.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you forgot about spaces in "This must be deleted". Did you try quoting the line ssed arguments?

```
ssed "s:\<tagnumberone\>\<tagInside\>This must be deleted\<\/tagInside\>\<\/tagnumberone\>::" <file.xml >out.xmle
```

Comment: No, I tried it. Then I have following error: The system cannot find the file specified.
 Even adding line breaks (\n) did not work, with or without single/double quotes...
If I add the line breaks \n, then the error becomes: The system cannot find the file specified...